# debug command line application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm wondering if it's possible to debug a command line application (where main received arguments argc, and **argv) in visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily set the command arguments to the executable from within Visual Studio, in the Debugging screen under Configuration Properties (at least that's where it is in 2005).

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it works the same way as in a GUI application. Set a breakpoint somewhere, and hit debug start.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Just set a breakpoint on `main`, and go to your project properties (under the Debug section if I remember right), then set the command-line arguments you want to debug with.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it be possible?  Set a breakpoint and start debugging.